# How to rebuild buildroot toolchain

Tags: embedded-linux, toolchain, buildroot

everybody!
I moved buildroot into another directory and buildroot toolchain didn't work because it refers to absolute path. How can I rebuild the toolchain? There must be some *-dirclean makefile targets to wipe toolchain out.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the current Buildroot, you cannot just rebuild the toolchain, you have to make a full rebuild of Buildroot, by doing:

```
make clean
make
```

This will completely remove your previous build results and rebuild your toolchain and system from scratch.

Comment: I certainly remember that I rebuilt this. But I forgot how I did this :)

Comment: Any update on this? 9 years passed, do we have same issue?

Comment: @0andriy, after rebuilding toolchain you should rebuild all target packages anyway, otherwise you can get a mess in compiled code and not stable results. I prefer to spend time building a predictable build to saving time with an unpredictable build )

Comment: @Mixaz, `ccache` helps with that. I rebuild Buildroot regularly and after updating it.